# Laravel migration errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I have a music_upload table which references both `album_id` and `user_id` from both album and user table. The `user_id` foreign key works fine, it is the `album_id` foreign key which spews out this error

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 
> Can't create table `nightingalev2`.`music_uploads` 
> (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 
> (SQL: alter table `music_uploads` 
> add constraint `music_uploads_album_id_foreign` foreign key (`album_id`) 
> references `albums` (`id`) on delete cascade)
> ```

This is my `album` table schema

```
Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('artist_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('artist_id')->references('id')->on('artists');
        });
```

This is my `music_uploads` schema

```
Schema::create('music_uploads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('album_id');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->string('extension');
            $table->string('artistname')->nullable();
            $table->string('albumname')->nullable();
            $table->string('playtime')->nullable();
            $table->string('genres')->nullable();
            $table->integer('length')->nullable();
            $table->string('filesize')->nullable();
            $table->string('location')->nullable();
            $table->string('thumbnail')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

And this is my `users` table schema if needed

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I changed from `$table->id()` to `$table->increment('id')` and it didn't work. Changed the `unsignedBitInteger` into `integer()->unsigned()` and still didn't work.

Comment: The error seems to mention the `albums` table. Does that have a compatible data type for its `id` column? Signed integers and unsigned integers are not compatible for this purpose.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you clarify in layman terms?

Comment: Signed integers and unsigned integers are not compatible with respect to foreign key relationships. They must either both be signed or both be unsigned. But you seem to have made them both unsigned, according to the code you show above. The `id()` shortcut is equivalent to `bigIncrements('id')` which results in a `BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` in MySQL parlance. Perhaps you created it with a different definition previously and the migration is using that? I'd go check in the MySQL client and use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` for each table to confirm the data types.

Comment: I checked in `albums` table and in `id` column it says, `id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Okay you can get a bit more detail on why MySQL thought it wasn't a proper foreign key by running the SQL statement `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`. The output is long, so you might want to use `tee status.txt` first to save it to a file. In the output, there should be a section for LAST FOREIGN KEY ERROR.

Comment: Here is the [link to the file] (https://ufile.io/sx1syjxw)

Comment: I don't see a section for LAST FOREIGN KEY ERROR in that report. Either you restarted the daemon since you tried your migration, or you took the status from the wrong instance.

Comment: It's highly likely that the `music_uploads` migration is running **before** the `albums` migration. Can you share the names of these 2 migration files?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa 2021_04_03_134426_create_music_uploads_table.php and 2021_11_11_195944_create_albums_table.php This one?

Comment: @BillKarwin I think I commented out the portion that was throwing the error so it may not show in the report.

Answer (score 3):

Your `2021_04_03_134426_create_music_uploads_table` migration is essentially running ***before*** the `2021_11_11_195944_create_albums_table` migration.

##### Solution.

### STEP 1

Rename:
`2021_04_03_134426_create_music_uploads_table`
To:
`2021_11_11_195944_create_music_uploads_table`

### STEP 2

Rename:
`2021_11_11_195944_create_albums_table.php`
To:
`2021_04_03_134426_create_albums_table.php`

### STEP 3

Re-run the migration(s).

`php artisan migrate`

### NOTES:

Always ensure that tables (migrations) with foreign key columns are created after the tables (migrations) they refer to.

In your case, you created the `music_uploads` migration on 03th/04/2021. And then created the `albums` migration on 11th/11/2021. Yet the `albums` migration had to be created earlier than that of `music_uploads`.

*Migrations are run in the order of their prepended timestamp.*